# how to set up wp in folder within static website?

Tags: permalinks, 404-error, server, apache

In my server I have the following file structure:

```
www/
  index.html
  js/..
  css/..
  img/..
  index.html
  ...
  blog/
    .htaccess
    index.php
    wordpress/
      .htaccess
      wp-config.php
      ...
```

Basically, www/ with some static files and the blog/ directory where I keep the wordpress files (so that if I want to login I have to go to www.mysite.com/blog/wordpress/wp-admin.php)

I have no problem login in, I have no problem displaying the front page, but when I try to access one of the posts or categories I am redirected to www.mysite.com/index.php and get the following error message:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I don't think it's an .htaccess problem, because both .htaccess files are there and I don't have any issues with permalinks while browsing the site locally... Any ideas on what could this be?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
        BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|js|js2|js3|js4|CSS|HTC|JS|JS2|JS3|JS4)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header unset ETag
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|SVGZ|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header unset ETag
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|JSON|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|MPP|OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|WAV|WMA|WRI|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header unset ETag
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC Browser Cache


# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(W3\ Total\ Cache/0\.9\.2\.9) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wordpress/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wordpress/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
```

Comment: I suspect that it is an `.htaccess` issue. Please post the content of your `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to copy the file `/blog/index.php` to `/index.php` and modify a line in the new copy you create:

```
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

to

```
require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Here is a complete guide to moving Wordpress into a separate folder: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: If you copy `/blog/index.php` to the server document root it could interfere with the static content in root.

Comment: You might also check the Wordpress Address and Site Address configuration options which are under Settings > General.  The Wordpress Address should point to the blog directory and the Site Address should point to the URL for the front page of your blog.

Are you trying to set it up so that your blog is accessible from the root of your website or from /blog/